# VB6 - Disable drop into webbrowser control

Tags: drag-and-drop, vb6, webbrowser-control

1. Create a form with a webbrowser control.
2. Drag and drop a txt/html file into the webbrowser.
3. **The file is shown into the browser.**

How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` control has a property: `RegisterAsDropTarget`. Set it to false.

[image: WebBrowser Properties]

You can get a little more info on the property (and other properties) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to disable drag-and-drop you should be able to set AllowBrowserDrop to "False".

Comment: That property isn't listed on the `WebBrowser` control.